# Adding function to plugin panel checkbox to change CSS

Tags: javascript, php, css, wordpress, plugins

I am developing a wordpress plugin and I create in the plugin admin panel a couple of options for a styling of an object in page, as you can see:

[image: 1]

As you can see, I want when the person clicks on of the checkbox, to automatically apply the CSS corresponding to the checkbox to the object.

```
function vsuc_page_html() { ?>
<div ..
    <form method="post" action="options.php">
        <?php settings_errors() ?>
        <?php settings_fields('vsuc_option_group'); ?>
  <...
    <h3 class= "styleChoose"> Choose display style </h3>
    <input type="checkbox" id="vsuc_checkbox1" name="vsuc_checkbox1" value="style1" checked>
    <label for="checkbox1"><img src="<?php echo plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ); ?>/img/style1.PNG" class="style1"></label>
    <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox2" name="vsuc_checkbox2" value="style2" checked>
    <label for="checkbox2"><img src="<?php echo plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ); ?>/img/style2.png" class="style1"></label><br>
    <...
```

And I have registered the checkbox here:

```
function vsuc_register_settings() {
    register_setting('vsuc_option_group', 'vsuc_text_field');
  register_setting('vsuc_option_group', 'vsuc_checkbox1');
```

Now, I have created another css callout to a new function that has the attributes for the layouts that you saw in the image - I have ".visitor_count" (first style) and ".visitor_count_style2".

I have tried doing this with EventListeners but it does not work :

```
function checkbox() {
    var checkBox = document.getElementById("vsuc_checkbox1");
    var checkClass = document.getElementById("visitor_count");
    if (checkBox.checked == true) {
        checkClass.style.display = "none";
    } else {
        checkClass.style.display = "block";
    }
```

I also have triend a jQuery code suggested by someone but i get an error saying:Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined.

```
    $("#vsuc_checkbox1").change(function () {
        let x = $(".visitor_count");
        if (this.checked) {
            x.hide();
        } else {
            x.show();
        }
    });
});
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using checkbox input, you should use radio button input. With the radio button the code will look like this:

```
function vsuc_page_html() {
        // form tags.
        settings_errors();
        settings_fields( 'vsuc_option_group' );
    ?>
    <h3 class="style-choose">choose display style</h3>
    <p class="form-group">
        <label for="radio-style1">
            <input type="radio" id="radio-style1" class="vsuc_radio_class" name="vsuc_radio" value="style1" checked />
            <img src="<?php echo esc_url( plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ) . '/img/style1.png' ); ?>" class="style1" />
        </label>

        <label for="radio-style2">
            <input type="radio" id="radio-style2" class="vsuc_radio_class" name="vsuc_radio" value="style2" checked />
            <img src="<?php echo esc_url( plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ) . '/img/style2.png' ); ?>" class="style1" />
        </label>
    </p>
    <?php
}
```

and This is how you'll write JS code to get selected radio button value:

```js
(function ($) {
    $(document).on("click", "input.vsuc_radio_class", function () {
        const value = $("input.vsuc_radio_class:checked").val();

        if (value === "style1") {
            // Do things for style 1.
        } else if (value === "style2") {
            // Do things for style 2.
        } else {
            // Do things for nothing.
        }
    });
})(jQuery);
```